# How to pick up values from multiple radio buttons and print in dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I cannot echo radio button values to a dynamic tables which is constructed from php.

I have succeed to have Jquery auto update "name" for the radio buttons for every added row. However, the radio value seems only pick up the value from the first row.

```
<?php
//Pick up the index Row for constructing the tables
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $row = explode("_", $_POST['rowNumber']);
    if($row[1] > 0){
        $maxRow =  $row[1];}
};
//Pick up form input
$vitalTime = $_POST['vitalTime'];
$vitalResRate = $_POST['vitalResRate'];

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $maxRow; $i++) {
        //Pick up radio form input
        $radCons = $_POST['radCons' . $i];

        var_dump($radCons);

        echo $i;
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        echo "<td>Vital time:" . $vitalTime[$i] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>Respiration: " . $vitalResRate[$i] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>Level of Conscousness ". $radCons ."</td>";

    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

```html
<form method="POST">
<div class="row cloned-row">
 <div class="col-sm">
   <h3>Time</h3>
    <input name="vitalTime[]" id="vitalTime_1" type="text">
 </div>
 <div class="vitalCons col-sm">
    <h3>Level of Conscousness</h3>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input name="radCons0" class="form-check-input" type="radio"  value="Alert">
      <label class="form-check-label">Alert</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input name="radCons0" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="Voice">
      <label class="form-check-label">Voice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input name="radCons0" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="Pain">
      <label class="form-check-label">Pain</label>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input class="btn" name="submit" type="submit"  value="Submit"></input>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input name="rowNumber" id="rowNumber" type="text" value="Row_1">   
</div>
</form>
```

```
var btnAdd = $('#btnAdd');
            btnAdd.click(function(){
                //Select last ID
                var vitalTime = $('.cloned-row .col-sm input[type=text]:nth-child(2)').last().attr('id');
                var vitalCons = $('.cloned-row .vitalCons input[type=radio]').last().attr('name');


                var split_id = vitalTime.split('_');
                var splitResRate = vitalResRate.split('_');

                //New Index
                var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;


                //Testing Variable 
                console.log(vitalCons);
                console.log(vitalResRate);
                console.log(index);


                $(rowNumber).val("Row_" + index); 
                //Create Clone
                var newRow = $(".cloned-row:last").clone(true);
                console.log(newRow);
                //Set id or name of new elements on cloned Row
                 $(newRow).find('.col-sm input[type=text]:nth-child(2)').attr("id","vitalTime_"+index);

                $(newRow).find('.vitalCons input[type=radio]').attr("name","radCons" + index);

                 //Set Value
                 $(newRow).find('.col-sm input[type=text]:nth-child(2)').val("vitalTime_"+ index);

                //Insert Element
                $(newRow).insertAfter(".cloned-row:last");
            });

            //Drop Vital Sign Table
            var btnDrop = $('#btnDrop');
            btnDrop.click(function(){
                $(".cloned-row:last").remove();
            });
```

I expect for every new row, the radio buttons should loop and ouput accordingly to the "index" variable. For example, radConsc1, radConsc2 and so on (generated by java-script when click "add" button in html) should be output but the radio button array can only hold the first value of radCons0 (testing from var_dump).

Comment: Firt of all you have a typo here: var vitalCons = vitalCons.split

Comment: thank you, but that line was accidental. The typo will not affect the logic flow at all.

Comment: I think issue is `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $row = explode("_", $_POST['rowNumber']);
    if($row[1] > 0){
        $maxRow =  $row[1];}
};` to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $row = explode("_", $_POST['rowNumber']);
    $maxRow =  count($row);
};`

Comment: Thank you Shoaib. However, the $row[1] is to pick up the number of max row from <input name="rowNumber"> in html. If I change to count($row), php will not pick up values and construct the tables correctly.

Comment: Thank you everyone coming by. I figure out what was the problem. I just need to change the ``name="vitalTable_1"`` to ``name="vitalTable_0"``, and change the Jquery for loop condition ``for ($i = 0; $i < $maxRow; $i++)`` to ``for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxRow; $i++)``.